# How do I give people rights in gerrit to see other people's rights

Tags: gerrit

I'm not having any issues setting up access rights with gerrit, except I'd like to give our developers the rights to see the rights that other people have. In particular, I'd like them to see who has Submit rights on a given repository so they know who to add to a code review when they've made a change.

Answer (score 0):

I think this information can be fetched from `refs/meta/config` file at [access section](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-project-config.html#access-section). One thing needs to be done is to give read permissions on that branch for the developer group